# Gateway Fields are not being displayed

Tags: cartthrob, stash

I am trying to use a template that I have custom Gateway fields in and I am using the following code

```
{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form return=""}
{gateway_fields}
<button class="checkout">Check Out</button>
{/exp:cartthrob:checkout_form}
```

But when the page renders there is just the EE embed tag instead of the fields.

I am using Stash variables to embed this form in the main page wrapper. I think it has something to do with the parsing order but I am not able to figure it out. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested it without using Stash or any sort of caching?

Comment: Yes if I take out the Stash it works fine. That is why I think it is something with the parsing order with Stash

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using gateway fields, try using the embed itself. This may help get around parse order issues.

You could alternately try using: 
http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/selected_gateway_fields/

{exp:cartthrob:selected_gateway_fields gateway="authorize_net"}

This might get around the parse order issues as well. I don't have stash set up, so I can't test unfortunately, so I'm just making guesses at the moment.